# Element alignment in G Chrome with absolute position

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, alignment, css-position

I want red square exactly overlap green one.
Everything works fine in FF, IE and Opera, but in Chrome red square aligning to the left, not center.
Also, I can affect only on #parent div and its children because I making a bookmarklet and I can't change other page elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #center { text-align: center; }
        #parent {
            position: absolute;
            display: inline;
        }
        #nested {
            background-color: #c00;
            width: 280px !important;
            height: 210px !important;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="center">
        <div id="parent"><div id="nested"></div></div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; width: 280px; height: 210px; background-color: #0c0;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please, advice!

When I elaborated on chrome properties, I found that chrome is forcing display to block when you set position to absolute for #parent. How to make it inline?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is *visually* what you asked for:

- I only changed the CSS for `#parent` and `#nested`.
- It looks the same in IE7/IE8, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari.

[***Live Demo***](http://jsbin.com/ipuri5)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #center { text-align: center; }
        #parent {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            /*top: 0;*/
            text-align: center
        }
        #nested {
            background-color: #c00;
            width: 280px !important;
            height: 210px !important;
            display: inline-block
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="center">
        <div id="parent"><div id="nested"></div></div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; width: 280px; height: 210px; background-color: #0c0;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Andrey: And you made no mention of that before. You're using `position: absolute` on `#parent` - of course it "won't work" inside a table cell. You can fix it by adding `position: relative` on `#center`, but according to you, I can't do that.

Comment: That's the problem - i can solve this issue for exact case, but it's hard to do if you don't know context(

Comment: @Andrey: So explain more throughly what you're doing. Do you have JavaScript available to position things? Can this creation you're making be placed *anywhere* on a page inside *any* element? Have you considered using an `iframe`? I can't help further without.. further information.